# How to Initiate a Call Notification as an Alert in Skype or Slack

Tags: python, slack, slack-api, skype, skype-bots

I'm looking to create a small tool that triggers a call to a user in Skype or Slack when an alert notification occurs. However, I've faced some limitations and complexities with the available APIs.

I tried using the Skype Web SDK, but Skype's APIs are mainly designed for handling incoming calls, not for initiating outgoing calls to users.
For Slack:
I used Slack's api.call.add, which returned a successful response for creating a call. However, I didn't receive any phone calls in Slack. I suspect that Slack may be using a different approach, such as huddle calling, rather than traditional API-based calling.